# add multiple columns with liquibase using yml

Tags: yaml, liquibase

I want to add multiple columns to my database using liquibase and a yml-file.
I know that I can do this with one step using xml like this:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="addColumn-example">
    <addColumn catalogName="cat"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="person">
        <column name="job" type="varchar(255)"/>
       <column name="designation" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>   
</changeSet>
```

Can I do the same in a yml-file?

```
- changeSet:     
    id: myId
    author: malt     
    changes:       
      - addColumn:           
        tableName: myTable           
        columns:             
          - column:               
            name: name01               
            type: decimal(21,2) 
          - column:               
            name: name02               
            type: decimal(21,2)
```

This does not seem to work...
I just don't want to repeat the -addColumn-Tag again and again.

Thanks for your help!

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

According to [addColumn](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-column.html) liquibase documentation you can do this in yaml as such (just their example):

```
databaseChangeLog:
   - changeSet:
       id: addColumn-example
       author: liquibase-docs
     changes:
         - addColumn:
              tableName: person
              columns:
                 name: middlename
                 type: varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, just need an extra indent after `column`:

```yaml
- changeSet:     
    id: myId
    author: malt     
    changes:       
      - addColumn:           
        tableName: myTable           
        columns:             
          - column:  # note the indent below here!             
              name: name01              
              type: decimal(21,2) 
          - column:               
              name: name02               
              type: decimal(21,2)
```